# c# any way for an anonymous class to escape an inner scope block?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

i want to use an anonymous class but instantiate inside a `using` code block and have it escape the block.  is this possible?

eg, i have

```
using (var s = something()) {
   var instance = new { AA = s.A };
   // ... lots of code
   Console.WriteLine(instance.AA);
}
```

And I would rather have something like:

```
var instance;  // <- nope, can't do this
using (var s = something()) {
   instance = new { AA = s.A };
}
// ... lots of code
Console.WriteLine(instance.AA);
```

Comment: create a concrete class and use that

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the point is to use an anonymous class.

Comment: A dynamic variable will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easily done:

```
var instance = new { Name = default(string) };
using (whatever) 
{
  instance = new { Name = whatever.Whatever() };
}
...
```

But the better thing to do here is to create an actual class.

Or, in C# 7, consider using a tuple.

Now, if you want to get really fancy...

```
static R Using<A, R>(A resource, Func<A, R> body) where A : IDisposable
{
    using (resource) return body(resource);
}
...

var instance = Using(something(), s => new { AA = s.A });
```

But this seems silly. Just make a class!

Comment: awesome.  thanks for the help!  the generic method technique is great.  you da man!

Comment: Note that this `Using` method introduces possible leaks of the disposable resource that an actual `using` statement wouldn't.  If the evaluation of the second parameter throws and exception then the resource isn't disposed of.  Depending on the disposable resource and how you use the method, that may or may not be a concern.

Comment: @CoderBrien Yes, I'm quite sure.  Once you get into the body of the method and into the `using` you're fine, but the problem is you aren't guaranteed to get there after you have already constructed the disposable resource.

Comment: @CoderBrien Like I said in my original comment, if the evaluation of the second argument throws an exception, then the disposable resource is leaked.  That's not really an issue in this particular case, because there aren't any realistic ways for it to throw, but there are plenty of other ways to structure the code such that it *could* happen.

Comment: @servy you are absolute right.  in my actual use i pass a function to create the object that gets called by the generic method to avoid this (ie a factory method)

Comment: @CoderBrien That would be one effective way to avoid that issue, yes.

Comment: @Servy: You are correct. I note however that `using` already has this problem.  Consider `using(foo()) bar();` This is logically the same as `var x = foo(); try { bar(); } finally { if (x != null) (IDispose)x; }`.  Suppose `foo()` throws *after* the unmanaged resource has been allocated; then the try block is never entered. Suppose a `ThreadAbortException` is thrown *between* the return of `foo()` and the assignment to `x`.  `using` is not now and has never been a guarantee that the resource is disposed in a world with exceptions.

Comment: @EricLippert The difference is that in the case of a `using` there are very few issues that can come up, a thread abort exception being one of very few possibilities.  In  your case you're executing user code, which is both more likely to have an exception than the possibility of a thread abort exception, but most importantly, it's something that you can actually prevent, unlike a thread abort exception.

Comment: @Servy: I try to be unconcerned with what is *likely*. Given enough time, everything possible is likely. I try to be concerned about what is *possible*. You are completely correct to note that it is *possible* that there is an exception between the resource being allocated and the try block being entered, and that you should consider this possibility and code accordingly. My point is that *you should have been doing that already anyways*, because the possibility was always there.

Answer (score 1):

I often write static `Use` methods for this purpose.

```
class SomethingDisposable : IDisposable {

   ...       

   public static T Use<T>(Func<SomethingDisposable, T> pFunc) {
      using (var somethingDisposable = new SomethingDisposable())
         return pFunc(somethingDisposable);
   }

   // also a version that takes an Action and returns nothing

   ...
}
```

Now you can just return whatever you want, even an anonymous type, and it'll always be safely wrapped in a `using`. These are very handy, for example, when working with Entity Framework.

```
var result = SomethingDisposable.Use(sd => sd.DoSomething());
var anonResult = SomethingDisposable.Use(sd => new { Property = sd.DoSomethingElse() });

// etc.
```